# Haskell curly brace parse error

Tags: haskell, archlinux, xmonad

Running Manjaro and trying to get XMonad to work I encountered a `parse error on input '{'` with the following `xmonad.hs`:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import System.IO

main = do
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"

  xmonad $ defaultConfig
  { manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
  , layoutHook = avoidStruts  $  layoutHook defaultConfig
  , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
          { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
          , pptitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 50
          }
  , modMask = mod4Mask   -- rebind Mod to the windows key
  } `additionalKeys`
  [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_z), spawn "xscreensaver-command -lock; xset dmps force off")
  , ((controlMask, xK_Print), spawn "sleep 0.2; scrot -s")
  , ((0, xK_Print), spawn "scrot")
  ]
```

I have found this [solution on su.sx](https://superuser.com/questions/470067/what-is-wrong-in-this-xmonad-configuration) and took my xmonad.hs from [readthedocs.io](https://beginners-guide-to-xmonad.readthedocs.io/configure_xmonadhs.html).
For getting started I would like to use that config file, I do not know however how to apply the solution to this. If somebody proficient could explain why that error appears and how to fix it, I'd really appreciate it since I just recently started with Haskell and it's really bending my mind to an unknown extent... :D

Comment: Well, what do you think how the compiler parses this code? (Draw parentheses) Hint: the solution on SuperUser that you've linked doesn't have the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent everything after the `xmonad $ defaultConfig` line further to the right (it seems some of the indentation was lost when you pasted [the example](https://beginners-guide-to-xmonad.readthedocs.io/configure_xmonadhs.html)):

```
main = do
    xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"

    xmonad $ defaultConfig
        { manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
        , layoutHook = avoidStruts  $  layoutHook defaultConfig
        , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
                        { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
                        , ppTitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 50
                        }
        , modMask = mod4Mask     -- Rebind Mod to the Windows key
        } `additionalKeys`
        [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_z), spawn "xscreensaver-command -lock; xset dpms force off")
        , ((controlMask, xK_Print), spawn "sleep 0.2; scrot -s")
        , ((0, xK_Print), spawn "scrot")
        ]
```

Lines at the "parent" indentation level in a do-block are parsed as separate statements, which is not appropriate here.